How do I make 2 separate models in a iOS SwiftData app, 1 of which will be in iCloud?
I'm working on an iOS SwiftData app that's an index for a series of 200 books, a comic book collection, with a store built into the app containing the relevant book data.
Ideally I want to separate the user data(owns volume, has read, notes) from the book data, volume data (includes stories, artists, writers etc).
I would like to have the user data sync via iCloud but don't want to be backing up the other data - partly because its doesn't need to sync but also because as the series isn't finished I want to push the updates for the book collection by shipping a new store in updates to the app.
How to I define UserData property and add it, separately, into the mix, so it's not in the books store (UCIndex.store)? but in its own thing that can be synced in iCloud
?
This is the code (working fine) as it currently stands for the Books data in the store
struct UC_IndexApp: App {
    
    let container: ModelContainer
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            UltimateCollectionTabView()
        }.modelContainer(container)
    }
    
    init() {
        let schema = Schema([
            Volume.self, Story.self, Artist.self, Writer.self, Colourist.self, Letterer.self
        ])
        do {
            guard let storeURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "UCIndex", withExtension: "store") else {
                fatalError("failed to find ucIndex.store")
            }
            
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documentDirectoryURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                   let documentURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("UCIndex.store")

                   // Only copy the store from the bundle to the Documents directory if it doesn't exist
                   if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentURL.path) {
                       try fileManager.copyItem(at: storeURL, to: documentURL)
                   }
            let config = ModelConfiguration(url: documentURL)
            
            container = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: config)
            
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to create model container \(error.localizedDescription)")
            
        }
    }
}

cheers

I assume you need to create a new configuration for the user data that you add to your model container and you can’t use relationships across the configurations so you need to handle that in some other way.
